# How to implement tables using div in Joomla Editor?

Tags: html, joomla, vertical-alignment

I am trying to change my code from html tables to divs in Joomla.
I found some answers but I need a specific guidance.

1. I have 3 by 3 table (each window can hold anything - text, video, picture...)
2. When using tables, it is easy to do "Vertical Alignment"

Now I need to translate the html with tables to div.
BUT...

1. cannot use css, should be pure html
2. and my resulting div "table" should be vertically aligned.

I did not post any code because it is simply a 3 by 3 tables...

**If it is not possible to do this without CSS, then how can I save my css code in Joomla's JCE editor? It keeps commenting it out.**

This is the part of the code:

```
<style>
#container {
    display: table;
    }
#row  {
    display: table-row;
    }
#left, #right, #middle {
    display: table-cell;
    padding-right: 15px;
    }
#left p, #right p, #middle p {
    margin: 20px 1px;
   }
</style>

<div id="container">
  <div id="row">
    <div id="left"> 
    </div>

    <div id="middle">
    </div>

    <div id="right">
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is what I see after I save in the editor:

```
<p>
    <style type="text/css" scoped="scoped">
        <!-- #container {
            display: table;
        }
        #row {
            display: table-row;
        }
        #left, #right, #middle {
            display: table-cell;
            padding-right: 15px;
        }
        #left p, #right p, #middle p {
            margin: 20px 1px;
        }
        -->
    </style>
</p>
<div id="container">
    <div id="row">
        <div id="left">&nbsp;</div>
        <div id="middle">&nbsp;</div>
        <div id="right">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why the CSS restriction?

Comment: Can you write why do you want to change tables to divs?

Comment: Well I want to use div and CSS, but unfortunately JCE editor comments it out. What should I do?

Comment: @Oded: I want to use CSS, JCE will not allow me :\

Comment: Is the CSS you're trying to save inline as part of the `style` attribute on the div, or are you putting it in a `<style>` tag in the document?

Comment: Use an editor that will? Learn how to enable CSS on JCE? You are trying to solve a problem caused by IDE restrictions - not the right way...

Comment: @Noyo: I will add the code above

Comment: You should put the `<style>` tag in the `<head>` of the document, see if that fixes anything.

Comment: @Noyo: Unfortunately Joomla does not allow to add headers in the articles. So I am guessing, there should be a way to manually add those css codes into its default template.

Comment: @A.S.Roma Ah, I see you edited your question, it's more clear now. I think the editor is trying to be clever by adding scoped css, but it's doing it wrong (the `<style>` tag should share an ancestor with the elements to be styled--see http://css-tricks.com/saving-the-day-with-scoped-css/ ). Also, scoped css isn't yet supported by most browsers (see http://caniuse.com/#feat=style-scoped) so for even that to work, you'd need to use a polyfill written in JS.

Comment: @A.S.Roma, you could also try using inline styles, e.g. `<div id="container" style="display: table;">` etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you add your own CSS file to the template?
This way you can re-use your CSS throughout the site instead of C&P in every article where you need it?

YooTheme provide a file for you called custom.css
You can edit this through `template manager/templates/yourtemplate name`
then look for custom.css on the right.

RocketTheme also provide provision for a custom file but you need to add it to the 
`templates/yourtemplatename/css` folder as
`yourtemplatename_custom.css`.  You can use ftp for this or upload it rhough your CPanel/Plesk if you use that. Actually doesn't JCE also add a file browser button to the control panel?  You may be able to add files through that.

Admittedly there are so many different ways template developers do this for their templates, it can be a little confusing but once you figure this out, it will save you hours of work.

Imagine changing one CSS entry and having all your articles reflect that change without having to edit each of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `div`s without CSS for such a layout.

It is simply not possible without CSS (and even then, not straight forward).

Comment: in that case how can i make JCE editor in Joomla to allow my css. It comments it when i try to save the code

Comment: @A.S.Roma - I have no idea. Never used that editor. Perhaps ask a new question about that (after searching, of course)?

Answer (score 0):

In your Joomla admin panel:

Components > JCE > Profiles > your_profile > Editor Parameters tab > Advanced tab:

Allow CSS (*) Yes ( ) No

Then, go to Site > Global Configuration > Text Filters and set your Filter Type to 'No Filtering'.

Comment: I set it to Yes. So it does not delete it, it just comments it out right after STYLE tag

Comment: I've been building Joomla sites with JCE for years. I've never seen it comment anything out. Either you're not writing proper code or something else is at play. Post some of the resultant HTML in your question, please.

Answer (score 0):

You should try moving your css that's within the style tags into the `<head></head>` tag at the top of your document. Maybe the reason your css is commented out is because you've enclosed it in `<p></p>` tags in the body of the document.

hope this is understandable.